# Simplifying coding using macro definitions

Tags: c, macros

I was trying to figure out someway to prevent writing everytime `typedef struct` then i found that i could do it using a macro definition this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define struct_t typedef struct

struct_t list {
    int id;
    struct list *next;
} list;

int main(void)
{
    list *element = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
    element->id = 7;
    element->next = NULL;

    printf("ID: %d\nNEXT: %p", element->id, element->next);
    return 0;
}
```

Structures are just an exemple: the whole think is about simplifing coding.

Is it a good practice to use macros to simplify coding? or it could cause some problems?

Is there any way to simplify coding other than using a maroc definition?

Comment: **Please do not do this.** Using macros to substitute arbitrary parts of the language is evil. The name of choice is even worse: it looks as if it was a type name itself.

Comment: @FiddlingBits sorry it's not about structurs it about simplifing coding. check the new title

Comment: (The best thing is that I *knew* I was going to get more than 5 upvotes in the first 10 minutes for that comment.)

Comment: the new title does not change the fact that it is a bad idea

Comment: There's no real need to use typedefs for structs at all. You can just write `struct list { /* ... /* };` and then refer to the type as `struct list`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Then you will always write `struct list` to declare a new element

Comment: @rullof: Yes. Personally, I have no problem with that. If a little extra typing makes the code more readable, it's well worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although macros do have their place in simplifying tedious, repetitive coding tasks, this is not one of the places where they would be helpful: you are saving six characters per `struct`, do not help you hide anything of complexity, while at the same time introducing a readability issue for readers of your code.

If you wish to save some typing, a better approach in this case may be defining a macro in your favorite IDE or code editor.

Although it is very hard to formulate rules for deciding on using a macro, in general you should consider the following points when making your decision:

- **Will macro simplify a complex block of code?** - If the answer is "no", you should not make a macro for it.
- **Will macro provide a nice name for a short block of code?** - Macro may be a good choice here. Another choice could be an inline function.
- **Are you replacing a single language construct?** - If the answer is "yes", you should refrain from using a macro.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to use macros to "hide" things.  It should be very clear to all people reading your code exactly what each and everything thing is.  My suggestion is to use macros only for simple definitions, such as ...

```
#define MAX_NUM (10)
```

... or in the case where a defining function isn't possible or much more complicated.  I can't think of a good example, but perhaps this poorly illustrates one of the rare exceptions ...

```
#define TRY(test)        if(test != 0)  \ 
                             goto fail; \
#define FAIL(fail_block) {              \
                             fail:      \
                             fail_block \
                         }              \
```

Comment: Dat pseudo-exception handler...! (I'd still do that using functions and `longjmp()`, though.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Hadn't thought of that.  I was having a hard time thinking of a good reason to use a macro! lol